# Проблема с DLL библиотеками QT

Tags: c++, qt, dll

Здравствуйте, работай со средой разработки QT, написав некоторый базовый функционал приложения, решил собрать ее и перенести на другой компьютер, проверить все ли корректно работает. Собирал программой DLLCollector. Все отлично собралось и заработало, но спустя пару недель написав не мало кода, решил опять собрать проект и перенести затестить, к удивлению стали требоваться dll библиотеки api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll, api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll. Я их начал искать в каталоге QT и MS VS там их не оказалось, потом скачал их из интернета, но не все так просто после потребовалась еще эта библиотека api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0.dll, которой попросту нет в интернете, есть только api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-2-0.dll, но она не подходит... Уже не знаю что делать, может кто-нибудь подскажет в чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить?

Comment: А компилятор MVC?

Comment: Да, я вот только что нашел библиотеки у себя на компьютере, где писал приложение в папке MS VS там как раз таки все api*.dll

Comment: Но api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll - не та версия, которая нужна...

Answer (score 1):

При компиляции приложений в *Qt* компилятором *Visual C++* (`MVC`) используются дополнительные *DLL*. Для из импорта требуется перенести все нужные библиотеки, а часто и установить беплатный распространяемый пакет *Visual C++*. Подробная статья [здесь](http://blog.harrix.org/article/5034).